# Problems with update query

Tags: php, mysql

I have a form in the previous page which allows users to fill in the details that they wish to edit which will be posted to another page.

```
 $first_name = $_POST['first_name'];
 $last_name = $_POST['last_name'];

$query = "UPDATE member SET first_name ='$first_name' WHERE member_id= '".$_SESSION['member_id']."'";
$query = "UPDATE member SET last_name ='$last_name' WHERE member_id= '".$_SESSION['member_id']."'";


// execute SQL statement
$status = mysqli_query($link,$query) or die(mysqli_error($link));
```

Apparantly, only the last query works. If the user edits the $first_name, the chang

Answer (score 1):

you only execute one query and as you overwrite $query with the second declaration you'll only execute the last...

you can update both in query like so:

```
$query = "UPDATE member SET first_name ='$first_name' ,last_name ='$last_name' WHERE member_id= '".$_SESSION['member_id']."'";
```

Answer (score 1):

Well, this is a basic Programming thing.

```
  $first_name = $_POST['first_name'];
 $last_name = $_POST['last_name'];

$query1 = "UPDATE member SET first_name ='$first_name' WHERE member_id= '".$_SESSION['member_id']."'";
$query2 = "UPDATE member SET last_name ='$last_name' WHERE member_id= '".$_SESSION['member_id']."'";


// execute SQL statement
$status1 = mysqli_query($link,$query1) or die(mysqli_error($link));
$status2 = mysqli_query($link,$query2) or die(mysqli_error($link));
```

Answer (score 0):

try combining query
$query = "UPDATE member SET first_name ='$first_name',last_name ='$last_name' WHERE member_id= '".$_SESSION['member_id']."'";

Answer (score 0):

You are changing the content of `$query` several times before executing. Apperently your `$query` contains the value that you last assignet to it.

This is the query that is then getting executed.